# Create Simple Website using DevExpress Templates

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web, devexpress

I'm new to .net world and I started to create asp.net web site.
So I Created a New Project using DexExpress template like below image[image]

When I was run, It appear as;

**A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)**

[image]

What is the reason for this ?

Is there any other way to use devExpress Templates ?

Sorry for wasting your valuable time for my basic problem here. Because I'm stuck here.

Thank you,

**EDITED**
here is my connection string,

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add name="DataConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;Connect Timeout=120" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Could you please share with us connection string declared in web.config file?

Comment: @V.S.SainiI have two connection string I dont know why is that ?

And Other this is Im new to .net and kind of confution with this ?
Thanks for youe help

Comment: I think one (ApplicationServices) is made as per Asp.Net to store security tables. Not sure! However another question - Do you have SQL Server Express installed on your PC?

Comment: @V.S.SainiI installed SQL server Installed on my pc and its running perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

*I suspect that either -*

1. Instance names are not configured properly in connection string.
2. Or the concerned Sql Server instance is not running.

Can you please let us know ***which instance of Sql Server is running*** on your PC?

You can see SQL Server Services by typing **services.msc** in *Run box*. Please see snapshot to understand how to get instance name.

[image: Sql Server Instances]